# WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified only on my computer

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-3.1

Currently I am receiving this exception when I try to debug a console application (.NET Core 3.1) **Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified** but comparing with other computers it doesn't happen.  There is no a cert file used to run it, there shouldn´t be an addition step but I still don't know why I am getting this exception.  I tried to run as administrator but nothing.

[image]

Code where it happens

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace AppNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
             Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                webBuilder
                    .UseStartup<Startup>())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                builder
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()); 
        
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
   en Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(Byte[] rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   en Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
   en Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert(ConfigurationReader configReader)
   en Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
   en Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.ValidateOptions()
   en Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<StartAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
   en Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
   en Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   en Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   en Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   en Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   en Application.Program.Main(String[] args) en C:\Application\Application\Program.cs: línea 12
```

Comment: Please don't post code as a graphic. Always post code so that we can copy, paste, and run to see what you're seeing. Then we can give you a tested solution. Right now all we can say is you need to make sure the file exists.

Comment: Updated, but not sure what file it refers.